# Yes/ No Is $(X,T)$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology

Given $X= \{ a, b , c, d , e\}$ and $T= \{ X , \emptyset , \{a\} ,\{c,d\}, \{a , c, d\} , \{b ,c, d, e\} \}$. Is $(X,T)$ is connected ?

My attempt: I think yes take any two open set $\{a\}$ and $\{a,c,d\}$  , we have  $\{a\} \cap \{a,c,d\} \neq \emptyset $ this implies that  $(X,T)$ is connected

Is its  True or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not connected because it is the union of two disjoint open subsets $\{a\}$ and $\{b,c,d,e\}$.

Comment: okks @JCAA   why u r  not considering $\{a,c,d\}$ as open set ?

Comment: To prove that the space is not connected, it is enough to find to disjoint open subsets that cover the space. I cannot simply take arbitrary two open subsets for this. I  need two particular subsets.

Comment: @JCAA  To be exact: two disjoint and *non-empty* open sets.

Comment: That is true, nonempty.